# Does django save method changes require new migration?

Tags: django, migration

After changing a model save method, is it required to run the makemigration command?
In which case (if there are) does changes in save method involve database migrations?

Comment: No, You don't need to run those migration commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save method doesn't need migrations to update the database
If the model is changed  then u need to apply migrations.
Every time there is a change in schema u need to apply data migrations,
If u are not changing the model then u need not apply migrations when u use the save method